# Basic question on transforming object into float

Tags: python, pandas, dataset, transformation

I am new at programming and I'm having this trouble:

`y = pd.to_numeric(final_list\[1\])`

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File pandas_libs\lib.pyx:2315 in
> pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_numeric
>
> ValueError: Unable to parse string "- "
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> Input In [66] in <cell line: 1>

```
y = pd.to_numeric(final_list\[1\])
```

> File
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\numeric.py:184
> in to_numeric values, _ = lib.maybe_convert_numeric(
>
> File pandas_libs\lib.pyx:2357 in
> pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_numeric
>
> ValueError: Unable to parse string "- " at position 265066"

I tried

```
y = pd.to_numeric(final_list\[1\])
```

and also

```
y = final_list\[1\].astype(float, errors = 'raise')
```

both say it is not possible because of "- "

What do I need to do? Transform "- " into NaN? How do I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solutions is to convert such non-convertible cases to NaN:

```
y = pd.to_numeric(final_list[1], errors='coerce')
```